# Does Android support thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, gcc, android-ndk

Does Android  support pthreads?
And why when i use -pthread option  i see the linker error:

i686-android-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <cxxabi.h>
extern "C" int printf (const char *, ...);
int main()
{
  try
    {
      pthread_exit (0);
    }
  catch (abi::__forced_unwind &)
    {
      printf ("caught forced unwind\n");
      throw;
    }
  catch (...)
    {
      printf ("caught ...\n");
      return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to use -lpthread? Should it not be sufficient to just include "pthread.h?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I could see in the docs you do not need to use "-pthread". Checkout following:
http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/#pthreads

Info from NDK offical docs states (android-ndk-r8\docs\system\libc\OVERVIEW.html):

```
PThread implementation:

   Bionic's C library comes with its own pthread implementation bundled in.
   This is different from other historical C libraries which:
    - place it in an external library (-lpthread)
    - play linker tricks with weak symbols at dynamic link time
```

So keep in mind that Bionic includes directly pthread as opposed to standard way you are used to (with -lpthread).

Comment: Can I trust to this link? Because it's not developer.android.com or their google group...

Comment: Check this one also: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-platform/Cq05PaLaZbE/discussion . In general, bionic includes many pthread functions but not all of them (e.g. pthread_barrier_wait() is missing).